# Using Blob WebWorker to send Synchronous XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-services, xmlhttprequest, web-worker

First off, I am very new to web services, web workers, and XMLHttpRequests, so please bear with me. Also, there are a lot of stipulations in my project, so solutions to "just do it this way" may not be viable.

So I have a web service set up to receive calls from an XMLHttpRequest in javascript, and it does this synchronously. This works fine, but it ties up the UI thread, and I would like to have a loading spinner run while making the requests to the server. Due to one issue, I can't have the program access external scripts on the web, so I am using a Blob to mask the "file://" preface.

I am also using an inline webworker to accomplish this. Now I'm getting to my actual issue. Spawning the webworker is fine, and I can create and send the XMLHttpRequest, but as soon as I call "send" everything exits. It will run no lines of code after this.

**Here's some code:**

Called from JS:

```
var blob = new Blob([document.querySelector('#getWorker').textContent]);

var blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
worker.onmessage = function (e) {
    alert(e.data);
}
worker.postMessage();
```

The worker:

```
var bigString = "";

var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://<ipAddress>/<serviceName>/Service.asmx/<method>';

if (invocation) {
    invocation.open('GET', url, false);
    invocation.send();   //*****EXITS AFTER THIS LINE*****//
    if (invocation.status == 200) {
            var responseText = invocation.responseText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
            responseText = responseText.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', '');
            responseText = responseText.replace('<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">', '');
            responseText = responseText.replace('</string>', '');

            postMessage("Success");
            //updateTable(responseText);
        } else {
            postMessage("Fail");
            //alert("Could not connect to database. Check your internet connection.");
        }
    var c = 0;
    var b = 1;
}

var q=1;
```

The debugger will just end after the "invocation.send()" line. No error, no status, no nothing. And that's where I'm lost.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Also, this exact code works when it is not in a WebWorker, so there's likely something about them that I do not understand.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems this was a Chrome issue. It apparently fails silently when there is a COR request blocked. Working to fix that now...

Answer (score 0):

Chrome problem. Silent fail if COR request is blocked. Firefox console shows more information on the error.